# collapsing lines <N chars with regex

Tags: regex

I have a file that looks like this:

```
>chr3:11131258-11134670(-)_3301
tcctgaagaaatccaaaacaccatcagatccttctacaaaaggctatact
>chr3:11131258-11134670(-)_3351
caacaaaactggaaaacctggatgaaatggacaaatttctggacagatac
>chr3:11131258-11134670(-)_3401
caggtac
>chr5:146697252-146699855(+)_1
taaggaagcagataatccggcctgatccggggctcaagtcccttccggcc
```

Where `>` denotes a header line, and otherwise lines contain a sequence of characters with length <= 50.

I would like to find lines with character sequences < some threshold (*N*), and collapse them into the previous sequence line. Doing so on the example should produce the following file:

```
>chr3:11131258-11134670(-)_3301
tcctgaagaaatccaaaacaccatcagatccttctacaaaaggctatact
>chr3:11131258-11134670(-)_3351
caacaaaactggaaaacctggatgaaatggacaaatttctggacagataccaggtac
>chr5:146697252-146699855(+)_1
taaggaagcagataatccggcctgatccggggctcaagtcccttccggcc
```

I am attempting to do this with regex, but am not having much luck. I am open to various technologies, but a plus if it can be done on the command line. (I have several files to process each containing > 1 million lines).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this regex: `^(>.*)\n(\w{0,49})$`, with the multiline option so the `^` and `$` anchors match the beginning and ending of each line.

Then replace with the matching groups representing the header line and second line of the match: `$1 $2`

Here's a demo on [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/tN4dN7/1)

Comment: Wow! Thanks, I was close to that but mine was too complicated. I made a few modifications so that the leading newline and header are removed: `[\r\n]+^(>.*[\r\n]+)(\w{0,40})$`